# enable user to download template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a very simple html template named my.html that is accessed simply by the `class Wifi` below, and I want to enable the user to download that same my.html document as a file. In `class File` I don't know how to access the template to place in the self.response.out.write argument.

Alternatively is there a way for the user to download the template using appcfg.py or the likes directly from the Templates subdirectory?

```
class Wifi(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        template_values = { }
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('my.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render( template_values))

class File(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, upload_type):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/script'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=my.html"
        self.response.out.write(??????????????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can simply read the template as a file and then write it out like this:

```
class File(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        with open("templates/my.html", "r") as f:
            data = f.read()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/script'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=my.html"
        self.response.write(data)
```

You may need to fix the path to your template. You probably want a different content type since a template is not really a script.

Comment: I had to remove "upload_type" from the def argument, and only then it worked for me. Can you tell me what the "upload_type" might be and what it adds?

Comment: I had copied that from your original code without realizing it. You don't need it.